# Email sending stops from aws linux server shows "Deferred: Connection timed out" , mails are stuck in queue, how to fix this?

Tags: linux, email, server

Working on AWS, linux server using core php. Php mail function working earlier but stops suddenly, all the mails are stuck in queue receiving very late after 1 hour, showing an error of "Deferred: Connection timed out". How to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

AWS throttles outbound traffic on port 25 and might be causing this, you can ask them to remove it if haven't done already.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/